# Why is componentDidMount method not being called in reactjs.net when I write on JSX

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, jsx, reactjs.net

I'm a noob and I'm trying to compile a JSX following this tutorial :

http://xabikos.com/2015/03/18/Using-Reactjs-net-in-Web-Forms/

using reactjs.net``

In my helloWorld.jsx

```
class PageContent extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount() {
               this.state = { name: "Hello World from ComponentDidMount" };
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: "Hello World" };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.state = { name: "Hello World from ComponentWIllMount" };
    }

    render() {

        return <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
    }

}
```

In my ReactConfig.cs

```
        ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
        .AddScript("~/Scripts/components/helloWorld.jsx");
```

In my Default.aspx.cs

```
        var env = AssemblyRegistration.Container.Resolve<IReactEnvironment>
        ();
        var objectModel = new { user = "React User" };
        var reactComponent = env.CreateComponent("PageContent", 
        objectModel);

        PageContent.Text = reactComponent.RenderHtml();
```

The page seems to works fine

it prints

> "Hello World from Component Will Mount"

But when I comment the Component Will Mount, I dont receive anything from DidMount, it only prints

> "Hello World"

Does anybody know why is this method never called ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In componentDidMount use `this.setState({ name: "Hello World from ComponentDidMount" });`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're not using `this.setState`. You are manually assigning a new value in `this.state`. React does not know to call `render` again to update your component, which is why your component doesn't update. It's not that `this.state` has not changed. It's that React hasn't been told to update what's shown on the screen. So, here's what happens with your code in terms of life cycles:

1. `constructor`: initializes everything (duh)
2. `componentWillMount`: In your case, setting `this.state.name`. **render does not occur yet**
3. `render`: renders `this.state.name`, which you have set in your `componentWillMount`
4. `componentDidMount`: sets `this.state.name` to your new value. **no instructions to update your render function**

If you use `this.forceUpdate()` in your `componentDidMount`, after you assign `this.state.name` to its new value, I believe it would update, but this is very bad practice. Use `this.setState` instead.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ name: "Hello World from ComponentDidMount" });
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ name: "Hello World from ComponentWillMount" });
}
```

As you've noticed in your code, `this.setState` isn't entirely necessary in `componentWillMount`, because `render` has not been called yet. But it's good to just keep things consistent.